# How to sort graphql query result by amount of objects in an array

Tags: reactjs, database, sorting, graphql

I'm trying to query all posts from the database and sort them according to how many likes they have.

I tried sorting by the likeCount but the posts shows up in random order.

I guess it is because the like count is calculated by the resolver and is not a number in the database.

I tried sorting it by the amount of objects in the "likes" array instead, but i couldn't make it work. Is it possible? Or how can i fix it?

Resolver:

```
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    async getPosts() {
      try {
        const posts = await Post.find().sort({ likeCount: 1 });
        return posts;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}




Post: {
    likeCount: (parent) => parent.likes.length,
    commentCount: (parent) => parent.comments.length,
    shareCount: (parent) => parent.shares.length
  },
  Query: {
    ...postsResolvers.Query,
    ...usersResolvers.Query
  }
```

Type definitions:

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    body: String!
    user: ID!
    sharedPost: ID
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    comments: [Comment]!
    commentCount: Int!
    likes: [Like]!
    likeCount: Int!
    shares: [Share]!
    shareCount: Int!
  }
    type Comment {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    body: String!
  }
  type Like {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
  }
  type Share {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    createdAt: String!
    user: ID!
  }
  type Query {
    getPosts: [Post]
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: not graphql problem ... DB

Comment: Solved the problem by adding a field which iterates 1 or -1 each time like is clicked, and sorting by that instead

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding a field which iterates 1 or -1 each time like is clicked, and sorting by that instead